Sending btc from phantom
My btc has been locked on phantom wallet for having rare sats, I tried using magic Eden to separate them but it was unsuccessful, anyway back to phantom and now I am completely unable to send even the small portion of btc I was able to before. It just returns an error and the phantom chatbot is absolutely useless, any further info on this would be greatly appreciated.

I’m voting to close this question because this site is for Solana dev Q&A, not wallet support
